# How to get select option value inside razor in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `<select>` tag in my view.
For example:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
 <div>
 <select>
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="alert1">Alert1</option>
  <option value="alert2">alert2</option>
 </select> 
 </div>
 <div id="preview">
  `enter razor code here`@ {            
    here i have to write condition based on
    the <select option> tag value,
    need to display respective viewbag.
  }
 </div>
</body></html>
```

From my controller I am passing a `viewbag`, e.g.:

```
 viewbag.alert1="some html template1".
 viewbag.alert2="some html template2".
```

My requirement is:

On selecting `<option>`, say if I select 'Alert1', then in the `<div id="preview">` I need to display the `viewbag.alert1` content. If the user selects 'Alert2' then in the `<div id="preview">` I need to display `viewbag.alert2` value.

I know, I can use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.alert1)` and `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.alert2)` to get the data but it should be displayed based on the value of `<select option>` tag. Inside razor tag, I need to get the value of the `<select>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.alert1 != null || ViewBag.alert2 != null)
{
    @if(ViewBag.alert1.Selected == true)
    { 
      ViewBag.alert.value;
    }
    @if(ViewBag.alert2.Selected == true)
    { 
      ViewBag.alert2.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi..what you have said is based on the value of viewbag. what i need is based on the value of select option.
On selecting <option>, say if I select option value is 'Alert1', then in the <div id="preview"> I need to display the viewbag.alert1 content. If the user select option value is  'Alert2' then in the <div id="preview"> I need to display viewbag.alert2 value.